# Using VM in the cloud for building android custom ROM

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, azure, google-cloud-platform, cloud

Can you use Virtual Machine created in the **cloud (AWS/GCP/Azure)** to build and bake the Android custom ROM on my own terms (means if I have to make my own features possible)? Does it act like Ubuntu installed on a physical device?

If it is possible, how may I do it? What would it cost?

Answer (score 1):

Hi @Sandeshpd you can create a **virtual machines** in any cloud service to build your custom ROM for android. This means you can create a ubuntu machine in GCP and use it like any normal ubuntu system. You can choose any available flavours of Linux or ubuntu and use them for your own requirements. Recommendation is Google cloud (**GCP**).

Coming to pricing of the setup is based on the **resources** which you are going to use like **Storage, Memory, Processor** etc., and the region where you want to create like **US,ASIA,EUROPE etc.**

This [document](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/setting-up-an-android-development-environment-on-compute-engine) will help to set up the environment and this [pricing document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/all-pricing) and [calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator) will help to choose and calculate the pricing.